# Applying a Program Definition fails with "unable to unify Prop with [goal]"

Tags: coq, proof

In Coq, I showed the associativity of `append` on vectors using:

```coq
Require Import Coq.Vectors.VectorDef Omega.
Program Definition t_app_assoc v p q r (a : t v p) (b : t v q) (c : t v r) :=
  append (append a b) c = append a (append b c).
Next Obligation. omega. Qed.
```

I now want to apply this equality in a proof. Below is the easiest goal that I would expect to be provable with `t_app_assoc`. Of course it can be proven by `simpl` - this is just an example.

```coq
Goal (append (append (nil nat) (nil _)) (nil _)
   = append (nil _) (append (nil _) (nil _))).
apply t_app_assoc.
```

This `apply` fails with:

> Error: Unable to unify "Prop" with
>    "append (append (nil nat) (nil nat)) (nil nat) =
>     append (nil nat) (append (nil nat) (nil nat))".

How can I apply `t_app_assoc`? Or is there a better way to define it? I thought I needed a `Program Definition`, because simply using a `Lemma` leads to a type error because `t v (p + (q + r))` and `t v (p + q + r)` are not the same to Coq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Prologue

I guess what you want to to is to prove that the vector concatenation is associative and then use that fact as a lemma.

But `t_app_assoc` as you define it has the following type:

```
t_app_assoc
     : forall (v : Type) (p q r : nat), t v p -> t v q -> t v r -> Prop
```

You basically want to use `:` instead of `:=` as follows.

```
From Coq Require Import Vector Arith.
Import VectorNotations.
Import EqNotations.  (* rew notation, see below *)

Section Append.

Variable A : Type.
Variable p q r : nat.
Variables (a : t A p) (b : t A q) (c : t A r).

Fail Lemma t_app_assoc :
  append (append a b) c = append a (append b c).
```

Unfortunately, we cannot even state a lemma like this using the usual homogeneous equality.

The left-hand side has the following type:

```
Check append (append a b) c : t A (p + q + r).
```

whereas the right-hand side is of type

```
Check append a (append b c) : t A (p + (q + r)).
```

Since `t A (p + q + r)` is not the same as `t A (p + (q + r))` we cannot use `=` to state the above lemma.

Let me describe some ways of working around this issue:

#### `rew` notation

```
Lemma t_app_assoc_rew :
  append (append a b) c = rew (plus_assoc _ _ _) in
  append a (append b c).
Admitted.
```

Here we just use the law of associativity of addition for natural numbers to cast the type of RHS to `t A (p + q + r)`.

To make it work one needs to `Import EqNotations.` before.

#### `cast` function

This is a common problem, so the authors of the `Vector` library decided to provide a `cast` function with the following type:

```
cast :
  forall (A : Type) (m : nat),
  Vector.t A m -> forall n : nat, m = n -> Vector.t A n
```

Let me show how one can use it to prove the law of associativity for vectors. But let's prove the following auxiliary lemma first:

```
Lemma uncast {X n} {v : Vector.t X n} e :
  cast v e = v.
Proof. induction v as [|??? IH]; simpl; rewrite ?IH; reflexivity. Qed.
```

Now we are all set:

```
Lemma t_app_assoc_cast (a : t A p) (b : t A q) (c : t A r) :
  append (append a b) c = cast (append a (append b c)) (plus_assoc _ _ _).
Proof.
  generalize (Nat.add_assoc p q r).
  induction a as [|h p' a' IH]; intros e.
  - now rewrite uncast.
  - simpl; f_equal. apply IH.
Qed.
```

#### Heterogeneous equality (a.k.a. John Major equality)

```
Lemma t_app_assoc_jmeq :
  append (append a b) c ~= append a (append b c).
Admitted.

End Append.
```

If you compare the definition of the homogeneous equality

```
Inductive eq (A : Type) (x : A) : A -> Prop :=
  eq_refl : x = x.
```

and the definition of heterogeneous equality

```
Inductive JMeq (A : Type) (x : A) : forall B : Type, B -> Prop :=
  JMeq_refl : x ~= x.
```

you will see that with `JMeq` the LHS and RHS don't have to be of the same type and this is why the statement of `t_app_assoc_jmeq` looks a bit simpler than the previous ones.

#### Other approaches to vectors

See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42302300/2747511)
and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49477427/2747511);
I also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27640467/2747511)
very useful too.

Comment: This has been very helpful, thanks! Only, I haven't been able to prove the rew/cast lemma (nor found anyone using it...). I actually have no idea where to start; unfold cast does not lead to anything useful.